# Converting Categories to shapefiles

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

I have created 2 Categories in a feature using classification.Now how do I convert them into new shapefiles?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include more detail?  Do you mean you've symbolised your data based on field values and you'd like to save the features for each value as a new shapefile?

Comment: Yes, my data is grouped into 2 classes based on a single field value. And I'd like to save this / transform this grouping into 2 separate new shapefiles.

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to export your group of features, use your classification to select them and then right-click the item in the table of contents then go Data->Export Data.  In the Export Data dialog box make sure you click 'Selected Features' from the Export drop-down menu.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this using a simple model in `Model Builder`.

[image]

Where the input file is your original file you want to split and the expressions are the definition queries selecting the records you are interested in exporting to a new shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use select by attribute to select the Field Values. then Export the selected features using @MappaGnosis answer. 
Another Method: using Definition Query in layer properties. you can query based on values and export each query. 
There is a tool named [Split Layer by Attributes](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14127) that you can use to split the layer by select a field .